# assertion failed: self.form property MUST be assigned

Tags: swift

I am using this library for Swift forms: https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms This is very similar to Eureka.

Here's an explanation of what I am trying to do:

I have 2 Pickers in my form. Picker1 is just a normal picker while Picker2 depends on the value of Picker1. So when the user changes the value of Picker1. Options in Picker2 should be changed also. To do this, here's my function:

```
func change_data(){
   row4.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = ["hello", "from", "the"]
        row4.value = "hello"
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I use the `reloadData()` to see the changes in the values of my 2 pickers. But unfortunately, I get the error: `assertion failed: self.form property MUST be assigned!`

I tried putting that code in the action of a button in top bar and it works.

```
 func submit(_: UIBarButtonItem!) {

        //let message = self.form.formValues().description

        //let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Form output", message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

        //alert.show()
        row4.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = ["hello", "from", "the"]
        row4.value = "hello"
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

But I need to call the `reloadData()` inside my function and not in button click.

Here's the viewDidLoad of my FormViewController:

```
 public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        assert(form != nil, "self.form property MUST be assigned!")
        navigationItem.title = form.title
    }
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this:
[image]

I have several pickers, and the last picker will depend on the chosen items from 2nd and 3rd. I call those functions to update the content of my last picker.

Here's my FormViewController class:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import SwiftForms

class ExampleFormViewController: FormViewController {

    struct Static {
        static let nameTag = "name"
        static let passwordTag = "password"
        static let lastNameTag = "lastName"
        static let jobTag = "job"
        static let emailTag = "email"
        static let URLTag = "url"
        static let phoneTag = "phone"
        static let enabled = "enabled"
        static let check = "check"
        static let segmented = "segmented"
        static let picker = "picker"
        static let birthday = "birthday"
        static let categories = "categories"
        static let button = "button"
        static let stepper = "stepper"
        static let slider = "slider"
        static let textView = "textview"
    }
    var val_territory = [Int]()
    var val_company = [Int]()
    var val_facility = [Int]()
    var val_specialty = [Int]()
    var putu_company = ""
    var putu_territory = ""
    var putu_facility = ""

    var str_territory = [String]()
    var str_company = [String]()
    var str_facility = [String]()
    var str_specialty = [String]()

    var territory: [Territory] = []
    var company: [Company] = []
    var facility: [Facility] = []
    var specialty: [Specialty] = []
    var row1 = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.picker, rowType: .Picker, title: "Territory")
    var row2 = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.picker, rowType: .Picker, title: "Company")
    var row3 = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.picker, rowType: .Picker, title: "Facility")
    var row4 = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.picker, rowType: .Picker, title: "Specialty")


    let name: String
    var form2 = FormDescriptor(title: "Create Shift Entry")

    init(_ coder: NSCoder? = nil) {
        name = "Bar"

        if let coder = coder {
            super.init(coder: coder)
        } else {
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)
        }
    }

    required convenience init(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(coder)
        load_data()
        self.loadForm()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "submit:")

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "cancel:")
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    func submit(_: UIBarButtonItem!) {

        //let message = self.form.formValues().description

        //let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Form output", message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

        //alert.show()
        row4.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = ["hello", "from", "the"]
        row4.value = "hello"
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func cancel(_: UIBarButtonItem!) {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_main2", sender: self)
    }

    private func loadForm() {

        let form = FormDescriptor(title: "Create Shift Entry")


        let section1 = FormSectionDescriptor(headerTitle: nil, footerTitle: nil)


        row1.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = str_territory
        row1.value = str_territory[0]

        section1.addRow(row1)


        row2.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = str_company
        row2.value = str_company[0]
        section1.addRow(row2)


        row3.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = str_facility
        row3.value = str_facility[0]
        section1.addRow(row3)


        row4.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = str_specialty
        row4.value = str_specialty[0]
        section1.addRow(row4)



        let section2 = FormSectionDescriptor(headerTitle: nil, footerTitle: nil)

        var row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.phoneTag, rowType: .Phone, title: "Scheduled Hours")
        row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.CellConfiguration] = ["textField.placeholder" : "e.g. 8", "textField.textAlignment" : NSTextAlignment.Right.rawValue]
        section2.addRow(row)

        let section3 = FormSectionDescriptor(headerTitle: nil, footerTitle: nil)
        row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.birthday, rowType: .DateAndTime, title: "Time In")
        section3.addRow(row)

        row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.birthday, rowType: .DateAndTime, title: "Time Out")
        section3.addRow(row)



        let section4 = FormSectionDescriptor(headerTitle: nil, footerTitle: nil)

        row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.enabled, rowType: .BooleanSwitch, title: "Missed Lunch")
        section4.addRow(row)


        let section5 = FormSectionDescriptor(headerTitle: nil, footerTitle: nil)

        row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.textView, rowType: .MultilineText, title: "Notes")
        section5.addRow(row)


        let section8 = FormSectionDescriptor(headerTitle: nil, footerTitle: nil)

        row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.button, rowType: .Button, title: "Add Staff Signature")
        row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.DidSelectClosure] = {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        } as DidSelectClosure
        section8.addRow(row)

        let section9 = FormSectionDescriptor(headerTitle: nil, footerTitle: nil)

        row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.button, rowType: .Button, title: "Add Supervisor Signature")
        row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.DidSelectClosure] = {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            } as DidSelectClosure
        section9.addRow(row)

        form.sections = [section1, section2, section3, section4, section5, section8, section9]

        self.form = form
        form2 = form
    }

    func load_data(){
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "orig_id", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        let facilityPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "facility = %@", NSNumber(integer: 1))

        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Company")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        let fetchRequestTerritory = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Territory")
        fetchRequestTerritory.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        let fetchRequestFacility = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Facility")
        fetchRequestFacility.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        let fetchRequestSpecialty = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Specialty")
        fetchRequestSpecialty.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        fetchRequestSpecialty.predicate = facilityPredicate
        let error:NSError

        do {
            let company_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            company = company_temp as! [Company]
            for t in company {
                val_company.append(t.orig_id! as Int)
                str_company.append(t.name! as String)
            }
            print(company.count)

            let territory_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestTerritory)
            territory = territory_temp as! [Territory]
            for t in territory {
                val_territory.append(Int(t.orig_id!)!)
                str_territory.append(t.name! as String)
            }
            print(territory_temp.count)

            let facility_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestFacility)
            facility = facility_temp as! [Facility]
            for t in facility {
                val_facility.append(Int(t.orig_id!)!)
                str_facility.append(t.name! as String)
            }
            print(facility_temp.count)

            let specialty_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestSpecialty)
            specialty = specialty_temp as! [Specialty]
            for t in specialty {
                val_specialty.append(Int(t.orig_id!)!)
                str_specialty.append(t.name! as String)
            }
            print(specialty_temp.count)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            // failure
            print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
    func get_facility_ter(company: Int!){

        //print("company: " + company)
        //print("territory: " + territory!)
        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "orig_id", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Territory")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        do {
            let territory_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            var territory2 = territory_temp as! [Territory]
            for t in territory2 {
                val_territory.append(Int(t.orig_id!)!)
                str_territory.append(t.name! as String)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // failure
            print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if let company2 = company{
            let companyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "company = %@", NSNumber(integer: val_territory[str_territory.indexOf(putu_territory)!]))
            let territoryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "territory = %@", NSNumber(integer: val_territory[company]))
            let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [companyPredicate, territoryPredicate])
            let fetchRequestFacility = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Facility")

            fetchRequestFacility.predicate = predicate
            print(companyPredicate)

            do {
                let facility_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestFacility)
                facility = facility_temp as! [Facility]
                str_facility.removeAll()
                val_facility.removeAll()
                for t in facility {
                    val_facility.append(Int(t.orig_id!)!)
                    str_facility.append(t.name! as String)
                }
                row3.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = str_facility
            } catch let error as NSError {
                // failure
                print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

    }
    func get_facility_com(company: Int!){

        //print("company: " + company)
        //print("territory: " + territory!)
        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "orig_id", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Company")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        do {
        let company_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        var company2 = company_temp as! [Company]
        for t in company2 {
            val_company.append(t.orig_id! as Int)
            str_company.append(t.name! as String)
        }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // failure
            print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        print(val_company.count)
        print(str_company.count)
        print(putu_company)
        print(str_company)
        print(str_company.contains(putu_company))
        if let company2 = company{
            let companyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "company = %@", NSNumber(integer: val_company[company]))
            let territoryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "territory = %@", NSNumber(integer: val_company[str_company.indexOf(putu_company)!]))
            let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [companyPredicate, territoryPredicate])
            let fetchRequestFacility = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Facility")

            fetchRequestFacility.predicate = predicate
            print(companyPredicate)

            do {
                let facility_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestFacility)
                facility = facility_temp as! [Facility]
                str_facility.removeAll()
                val_facility.removeAll()
                for t in facility {
                    val_facility.append(Int(t.orig_id!)!)
                    str_facility.append(t.name! as String)
                }
                row3.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = str_facility
            } catch let error as NSError {
                // failure
                print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

    }
    func get_specialty(facility_txt: Int!){
        print("VALUE OF FACILITY: " + String(facility_txt))
        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "orig_id", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]


        let facilityPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "facility = %@", NSNumber(integer: val_facility[str_facility.indexOf(putu_facility)!]))
        let fetchRequestSpecialty = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Specialty")

        fetchRequestSpecialty.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        fetchRequestSpecialty.predicate = facilityPredicate

        do {
            let specialty_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestSpecialty)
            specialty = specialty_temp as! [Specialty]

            str_specialty.removeAll()
            val_specialty.removeAll()
            for t in specialty {
                val_specialty.append(Int(t.orig_id!)!)
                str_specialty.append(t.name! as String)
            }
            print(str_specialty)
            self.form = form2

            row4.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = str_specialty
            row4.value = "hello"
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // failure
            print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    func put_company(putu: String!, row: Int!){
        print("haler")
        putu_company = putu
        print(putu_company)
        print(row)
        get_facility_com(row)
    }
    func put_territory(putu: String!, row: Int!){
        print("haler")
        putu_territory = putu
        print(putu_territory)
        print(row)
        get_facility_ter(row)
    }
    func put_facility(putu: String!, row: Int!){
        print("haler")
        putu_facility = putu
        print(putu_facility)
        print(row)

        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "orig_id", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        let fetchRequestFacility = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Facility")
        fetchRequestFacility.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        do {
        let facility_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestFacility)
        facility = facility_temp as! [Facility]
        for t in facility {
            val_facility.append(Int(t.orig_id!)!)
            str_facility.append(t.name! as String)
        }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // failure
            print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        print(val_facility)
        get_specialty(val_facility[row])
    }


}
```

I call those functions here:

```
import UIKit

public class FormPickerCell: FormValueCell, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    // MARK: Properties

    private let picker = UIPickerView()
    private let hiddenTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectZero)

    struct MyVariables {
        static var mv_territory = 0
        static var mv_company = 0
        static var mv_facility = 0
        static var mv_specialty = 0
    }

    // MARK: FormBaseCell

    public override func configure() {
        super.configure()
        accessoryType = .None

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        hiddenTextField.inputView = picker

        contentView.addSubview(hiddenTextField)
    }

    public override func update() {
        super.update()

        titleLabel.text = rowDescriptor.title

        if let value = rowDescriptor.value {
            valueLabel.text = rowDescriptor.titleForOptionValue(value)
            if let options = rowDescriptor.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] as? NSArray {
                let index = options.indexOfObject(value)
                if index != NSNotFound {
                    picker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override class func formViewController(formViewController: FormViewController, didSelectRow selectedRow: FormBaseCell) {

        if selectedRow.rowDescriptor.value == nil {
            if let row = selectedRow as? FormPickerCell {
                let options = selectedRow.rowDescriptor.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] as? NSArray
                let optionValue = options?[0] as? NSObject
                selectedRow.rowDescriptor.value = optionValue
                row.valueLabel.text = selectedRow.rowDescriptor.titleForOptionValue(optionValue!)
                row.hiddenTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

            }
        } else {
            if let row = selectedRow as? FormPickerCell {
                guard let optionValue = selectedRow.rowDescriptor.value else { return }
                row.valueLabel.text = selectedRow.rowDescriptor.titleForOptionValue(optionValue)
                row.hiddenTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
        }
    }

    // MARK: UIPickerViewDelegate

    public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return rowDescriptor.titleForOptionAtIndex(row)
    }

    public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let options = rowDescriptor.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] as? NSArray
        let optionValue = options?[row] as? NSObject
        rowDescriptor.value = optionValue
        valueLabel.text = rowDescriptor.titleForOptionValue(optionValue!)
        if(rowDescriptor.title == "Company"){
            print("company")
            print(valueLabel.text)
            ExampleFormViewController().put_company(valueLabel.text, row: row)
        }else if(rowDescriptor.title == "Territory"){
            print("territory")
            print(valueLabel.text)
            ExampleFormViewController().put_territory(valueLabel.text, row: row)
        }
        else if(rowDescriptor.title == "Facility"){
            print("facility")
            print(valueLabel.text)
            ExampleFormViewController().put_facility(valueLabel.text, row: row)
        }

    }

    // MARK: UIPickerViewDataSource

    public func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if let options = rowDescriptor.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] as? NSArray {
            return options.count
        }
        return 0
    }
}
```

I do that to put new values to my picker whenever the selected item in other pickers change.

Comment: It is now the same @matt

Comment: If you want people to answer, you will have to simplify the code into minimal example. There is too much code that has no importance to the problem and somehow I feel that some important parts are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is in `FormPickerCell` in `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` method:

```
ExampleFormViewController().put_territory(valueLabel.text, row: row)
```

In this line you are creating a **new** instance of `ExampleFormViewController`. And I assume you want to call this function on your existing controller instance.

The easiest (and the wrongest) solution would be to use `FormBaseCell. formViewController` property:

```
public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let options = rowDescriptor.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] as? NSArray
    let optionValue = options?[row] as? NSObject
    rowDescriptor.value = optionValue
    valueLabel.text = rowDescriptor.titleForOptionValue(optionValue!)
    let controller = formViewController as! ExampleFormViewController
    if(rowDescriptor.title == "Company"){
        controller.put_company(valueLabel.text, row: row)
    } else if(rowDescriptor.title == "Territory"){
        controller.put_territory(valueLabel.text, row: row)
    } else if(rowDescriptor.title == "Facility"){
        controller.put_facility(valueLabel.text, row: row)
    }
}
```

But correct solution for SwiftForm would be to use standard `FormPickerCell` (don't override it with custom logic just for one controller!) and use `row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.DidUpdateClosure]`:

```
private func loadForm() {
    let form = FormDescriptor(title: "Create Shift Entry")
    let section1 = FormSectionDescriptor(headerTitle: nil, footerTitle: nil)

    row1.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = str_territory
    row1.value = str_territory[0]
    row1.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.DidUpdateClosure] = { [weak self] rowDescriptor in
        guard let value = rowDescriptor.value else { return }
        guard let options = rowDescriptor.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] as? NSArray else { return }
        let index = options.indexOfObject(value)
        self?.put_territory(rowDescriptor.titleForOptionValue(value), row: index)
    }
    section1.addRow(row1)

    /// add corresponding DidUpdateClosure for row2 and row3
    /// ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try to implement this now

Comment: Awww. My xcode is updating. What does DidUpdateClosure do? It is being fired right after what?

Comment: It's called after row.value changed: https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms/blob/master/SwiftForms/descriptors/FormRowDescriptor.swift#L96